# Custom == operator not used when comparing an object with itself with #include?

Tags: ruby, equality

The [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) for `Array#include?` specify that inclusion is checked using the `==` operator. I am checking this in the case of comparing an object with itself using a custom defined `==`:

```rb
class Foo
  def ==(other)
    false
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f == f # => false
```

In such case, the doc's description is not the case, and another mechanism is taking precedence:

```rb
[f].include?(f) # => true
```

What is this mechanism and where is it defined?

Comment: There are many other methods in `Array` that are described to use `==`, and `include?` is just one example.

Comment: Unless you have special reason, don't cite an old Ruby 2.2.2 code. Cite Ruby 2.6.0. The description may not have changed, but you can get unexpected results in the answers. In fact, VP. cites Ruby 2.2.2 code because you did.

Comment: exactly @sawa, that's what happened!

Comment: BTW, you can remove the version number from the URI and it will automatically redirect to the most recent official release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reading the source code

```
               VALUE
rb_ary_includes(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    long i;
    VALUE e;

    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        e = RARRAY_AREF(ary, i);
        switch (rb_equal_opt(e, item)) {
          case Qundef:
            if (rb_equal(e, item)) return Qtrue;
            break;
          case Qtrue:
            return Qtrue;
        }
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

from https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F you will see that ruby isn't using your object operator

EDIT: As stated by aleksei-matiushkin (in the comments), `rb_equal_opt(e, item)` compares the pointers and returns true

Inverting it, you can hit it with:

```
class Foo
  def ==(other)
    puts "yay"
    true
  end
end

> f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x0000000001048610> 
> [f].include?(f)
=> true 
> [f].include?(f.dup)
yay
=> true
```

Comment: It’s not using the `#==` operator only because that’s literally the same object and comparison of pointers immediately returns `true`. If that was not the case, `rb_equal` would call `#==`. The last clause `case Qtrue: return Qtrue;` is what’s returning `true`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now! The missing piece for me was to understand that `rb_equal_opt` compares pointers. Browsing throught Ruby's source code I still can't find this documented, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Dani you can find it here https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b4bc6ccb4ebf8be89ae0a7fa5f7e764a1cefac86/vm_insnhelper.c#L1502

Comment: @Dani and a nice reading here https://pawelniewiadomski.com/2017/03/21/making-ruby-array-include-faster/

Comment: @VP Yep I found the definition myself, it's the documentation I'm missing :) Looking at this code It's not immediatly clear to me that this is in fact pointer comparison.

Comment: @Dani according to the docs for [`BasicObject#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D) " At the Object level, == returns true only if obj and other are the same object." `Array#include?` is using this fact to avoid an expensive method call. Your implementation of `==` breaks this promise, so you shouldn't be surprised when built-in methods don't respect it

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the source code from this: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F

I believe that ruby used default operator (`rb_equal`) instead of object operator for this function.

Comment: Exactly the opposite. `rb_equal_opt(e, item)` comparing _the pointers_ returns `true` and `rb_equal` (that calls `#==`) is never called for the performance reasons.

Comment: Come on, Ruby 1.9.3 is dead. Check with at least Ruby 2.2.2, which is cited by the OP, or the newest Ruby 2.6.0, which is preferable.